# Instantiate from raycast without intersect

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, instantiation

So I want to know how to instantiate a GameObject without intersection in Unity3D.  As of now, the sphere instantiates intersected with the object that I hit with the raycast.  I am using the location of hit.point, but would like to know if there is a way to spawn it on the collisions instead of the origin of the object.  Here is my code for reference:

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class BallSpawn : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int castLength = 100;
    public GameObject spawnObject;
    
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        //Input.GetMouseButton for infinite
        if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
        {
            SpawnBall();
        }
            

    }

    public void SpawnBall()
    {
        RaycastHit hit;
        
        Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward) * castLength, Color.green, Mathf.Infinity);
        if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward), out hit, castLength))
        {
            Instantiate(spawnObject, hit.point, hit.transform.rotation);
        }
    }
}
```

As of now, the spheres clip into the ground and bounce out when they are spawned.  I would like it for the spheres to be "placed" so to speak, so that they spawn without clipping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to replace `hit.point` with `hit.point + hit.normal * ballRadius` (of course you must know or be able to get what the ball radius is). But this will result with some spawn positions being off, especially if you hit a surface under small angle.

Better alternative is to replace ray cast with `Physics.SphereCast (transform.position, sphereRadius, transform.forward, out hit, castDistance)`. This should give you good results but again you will still have to add the ball radius along the hit normal just like the raycast.

Comment: "would like to know if there is a way to spawn it on the collisions instead of the origin of the object". The `hit.point` is actually the point of the collision. Check the [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RaycastHit-point.html)

Comment: @rustyBucketBay He probably means collision/origin form the POW of the spawned object.

Comment: So, the collision "box" of the spawned object.  Right now, I have the sphere, which is my spawned object.  Whenever I try to spawn it, it clips through the floor and bounces out. I want to spawn it as if I were just placing the sphere on the ground, just to clarify.

Comment: Neither of these worked.  The same result is still there.

Comment: I have tested it and the balls spawn on the surface. Here is the exact code I used: https://pastebin.com/6aM6qibs